# Does unmounting a hard drive extend its life?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a couple of home made (non enterprise) servers with backup HDDs installed on them.

Since the purpose of these HDDs is only to store backups, I only use them at the time of performing the backups themselves, so is it a good practice to unmount the disks after making the backups and then mounting them back before making the next backup?

The idea behind is to extend the life of the HDDs avoiding disk usage (read/write) by any kind of process and maybe reduce a bit energy consumption although disk still consumes.

Considerations:

- HDDs are internal and cannot be external, so it is not feasible to unplug the disks at any moment.
- Unmounting/mounting drives to extend their life is considered since it is an automatable process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the lifespam of the disks will not change anything if you mount/umount them.

The main issues changing the life of a hard disk are the temperature, read and write cycles, and starting/stopping the motor driving the plates. Umounting the HDD after a backup will not change any of those.